# AVPlayer, how to play video with sound if iPhone stay in silents mode?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have simple example.
1) i create AVPlayerViewController in Interface builder
2) i create own custom class extend of AVPlayerViewController
3) i write several line of code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://188.143.133.203/106.3/index.m3u8")
        self.player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
        self.player?.play()
    }
```

I`ts better works, but if device state in silents mode then my video play without sound.

I tray turn on sound in player manually, like this:

```
self.player?.muted = false
self.player?.volume = 1.0
```

but its not work too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your audio session's category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` (and activate it).

Comment: I add in my code one line try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback) and all works. Thx, but you say what i should activate it. How i can do it?